# Computing and integrating the Gaussian curvature if the real Grassmannian G(1,3)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, grassmannian

I am trying teach myself the basics of curvature by doing concrete computations.
I would like to check the Gauss-Bonnet formula for the real Grassmannian $G(1,3)$ of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is nothing but the real projective plane.
I see it as the set of all rank 1 projections in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$, which sit in the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^9$ when we equip $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ with the Frobenius norm.
If possible, I would like to use the following parametrization
$$(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^3\longmapsto\frac{1}{1+s^2+t^2}\begin{bmatrix}1&s&t\\s&s^2&st\\t&st&t^2\end{bmatrix}$$
for all but one element of $G(1,3)$.

**Question 1:** How does one compute the Gaussian curvature $\mathcal{K}$ at a given point using the latter?

**Question 2:** What is the area form $\mathrm{d}A$ at such a point in the formula and how can I integrate the Gaussian curvature and check the Gauss-Bonnet formula
$$\int_{G(1,3)}\mathcal{K}\,\mathrm{d}A=2\pi\chi(G(1,3)) \,?$$

**Remarks:**

- I already know how to show that $\chi(G(1,3))=1$, so this question is really about the LHS of the formula above.
- Since this parametrization covers the whole $G(1,3)$ but one point, I expect it is enough to use the above parametrization, although I'm note sure.

Comment: To calculate $K$, you first calculate the $g$ and use the formula. It's long but routine.

Comment: @ArcticChar It is not routine for me, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Did you calculate $g$?

Comment: @ArcticChar No, I don't know how to do this. I'm a total beginner in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: $g$ is the $2\times 2$ metric $\begin{pmatrix}  \partial _s \cdot \partial_s &  \partial _s \cdot \partial_t  \\  \partial _t \cdot \partial_s  &  \partial _t \cdot \partial_t\end{pmatrix}$, where $\partial_s, \partial _t$ are the partial derivative of your parametrizations and $\cdot$ is the usual dot product in $\mathbb R^9$. After that, you can just the usual formula for $K$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this looks like a rather messy calculation. Any reason why you want to use this parameterization?

Comment: @Deane I like this parameterization because it comes from the usual affine coordinates on G(1,3). But if it's too messy, I'll be happy with another one.